# passing arguments through link to custom methods in rails Simple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just getting to grips with ruby and ruby on rails. I have links which toggle an object between two states - reject and approve. currently they are two separate links. here is an example of the reject method in the controller one

```
  def toggle_reject_field
    @entry.reject!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end    
  end
```

and the link that calls it

```
 link_to "Reject", (toggle_reject_field_admin_entry_path(photo, params.except(:controller, :action))), :remote => true
```

I have essentially the same for the approve link. But surely in Ruby there is a much more syntactical, friendly way of achieving this - something more dry.

so my bet is passing an 'reject' or 'approve' article in each link both pointing to the same controller method, but I cant seem to get it working.

this is my link

```
link_to "Approve", (toggle_field_admin_entry_path(photo, params.except(:controller, :action), 'approve')), :remote => true

  def toggle_field(object)
    if object == "approve"
      @entry.approve!
    else
      @entry.reject 
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

when i click it it does nothing, no action. So firstly, how do I get this working? Secondly, am I thinking about this in the right way? as in, like when i do something like this?

```
    2.1.0 :0 > def stats(object)
    2.1.0 :0>   "hello #{object}"
    2.1.0 :0>   end
     => :stats 
2.1.0 :0 > puts stats('bill')
hello bill
```

UPDATE: I have tried implemented something along the lines of what Mr Yoshi has posted, but it neither works nor answers my question. Can anybody help to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we usually do in these cases:

```
# routes.rb
resources :entries do
  get :toggle_field, on: :member # make sure to place this in the right namespace (ex: `/admin` )
end

# anchor tag
link_to 'toggle State', toggle_field_entry_path(entry.id)

# Entries Controller
def toggle_field
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  @entry.toggle_state.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to path_to_your_resource_edit_page }
    format.json { state: @entry.state }
  end
end

# Entry Model
def toggle_state
  self.state = (self.state == 'approve') ? 'reject' : 'approve'
end
```

If you want the default to be rejected (if `entry.state` is `nil`), reverse the test like this:

```
# Entry Model
def toggle_state
  self.state = (self.state == 'reject') ? 'approve' : 'reject' # if state.nil? || state == 'reject' ; set state to 'approve'
end
```

Comment: thanks for your response?, what about the link_to ? where does the action come from>

Comment: I get this error = undefined method `toggle_state' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I am just unsure about the link_to bit, i think i uderstand what you have done here

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggested `link_to`, but the path Helper given might not match your routes configuration @rico_mac